# How to check for an internal edge via TraCI?

Tags: veins, sumo

I am trying to figure out whether an edge/lane is internal. When SuMO creates internal edges/lanes, it prefixes them with a colon [[1](http://sumo.dlr.de/w/index.php?title=Networks/SUMO_Road_Networks&oldid=10730)]. Currently, I am [exploiting this information](https://github.com/sommer/veins/pull/70), however, it seems that you also can annotate arbitrary other edges as internal using the tag [`function`](http://sumo.dlr.de/w/index.php?title=Networks/SUMO_Road_Networks&oldid=10730). This is also set for internal edges created by SuMO [[1](http://sumo.dlr.de/w/index.php?title=Networks/SUMO_Road_Networks&oldid=10730)]. Therefore, I want to retrieve the information via TraCI.

To my knowledge, there is no TraCI command to retrieve this information (i.e. either the value of `function` or whether the edge/lane is internal).
The classes [`MSEdge`](https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/blob/v0_32_0/src/microsim/MSEdge.h) and [`MSLane`](https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/blob/v0_32_0/src/microsim/MSLane.h) in the [*microsim*](https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/tree/v0_32_0/src/microsim) directory have methods to retrieve both of those values, however, the classes [`Edge`](https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/blob/v0_32_0/src/libsumo/Edge.h) and [`Lane`](https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/blob/v0_32_0/src/libsumo/Lane.h) from [*libsumo*](https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/tree/v0_32_0/src/libsumo) do not.

I also checked whether the value of the `function` tag might get added to the parameter map during initialization, which I could access via TraCI's [`getParameter`](http://sumo.dlr.de/w/index.php?title=Traci/GenericParameters&oldid=10695#get_parameter). This also does not seem to be the case. I checked some files from the [*netimport*](https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/tree/v0_32_0/src/netimport) directory but could not find anything satisfactory.

Is there any other way to retrieve the function/isInternal information via TraCI without adding a new TraCI command (and the aforementioned missing methods in *libsumo*)?

Answer (score 3):

This is a static property of the network so the easiest way of retrieving the information is to parse the network. In Python you can use sumolib for that:

```
import sumolib
net = sumolib.net.readNet("my.net.xml")
function = {}
for e in net.getEdges():
    function[e.getID()] = e.getFunction()
```

There is currently no TraCI call for that but the colon thing is a very good indicator. The main developers are also a bit reluctant to add all static information retrieval to the TraCI API in order not to overload it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually do not want to parse the network myself, since SuMO is doing that and maintaining the information about the edge being internal already. Therefore, I think I will just implement the missing methods  and the TraCI call on my own.